# Telegram Bot to Download files from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

how can I utilize my telegram bot (node.js telegram bot api) to send random images saved in my google drive folder

Answer (score 0):

You must first learn to use the Google drive API: [Here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

I think you can do like this :

1. Get the file ID of all your images and put these ID into a list
2. Generate a random index for the list of IDs
3. Download the image and send it with the api of telegram

Comment: I am Newbie can you eleborate more with code , and also can I do that using two diifferent .Js files so that i can put Drive Api inside one and call it from other With Telegram api and How can i do that ?